# Select columns if any of their rows contain a certain string

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to obtain a list of columns in a DataFrame if any value in a column contains a string.  For example in the below dataframe I would like a list of columns that have the % in the string. I am able to accomplish this using a for loop and the series.str.contains method but doens't seem optimal especially with a larger dataset. Is there a more efficient way to do this?

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A': {0: '2019-06-01', 1: '2019-06-01', 2: '2019-06-01'},
                   'B': {0: '10', 1: '20', 2: '30'},
                   'C': {0: '10', 1: '20%', 2: '30%'},
                   'D': {0: '10%', 1: '20%', 2: '30'},
               })
```

#### DataFrame

```
            A   B    C    D
0  2019-06-01  10   10  10%
1  2019-06-01  20  20%  20%
2  2019-06-01  30  30%   30
```

#### Current Method

```
col_list = []
for col in df.columns:
    if (True in list(df[col].str.contains('%'))) is True:
        col_list.append(col)
```

#### Output

```
['C', 'D']
```

Comment: Why not just call `df.dtypes` ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First use [`DataFrame.select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) for filter only object columns, obviously string columns.

Then use [`DataFrame.applymap`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.applymap.html) for elementwise check values with [`DataFrame.any`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.any.html) for return True if at least one per column, so possible filter columns:

```
c = df.columns[df.select_dtypes(object).applymap(lambda x: '%' in str(x)).any()].tolist()
print (c)
['C', 'D']
```

Or use [`Series.str.contains`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.contains.html) per columns, `na` parameter should be omit if all strings columns:

```
f = lambda x: x.str.contains('%', na=False)
c = df.columns[df.select_dtypes(object).apply(f).any()].tolist()
print (c)
['C', 'D']
```

Comment: Not OP but thanks for the succinct answer. Your first method, if I'm not mistaken, will only work if dtypes of all the columns are str right?

Answer (score 16):

#### `stack` with `any`

```
df.columns[df.stack().str.contains('%').any(level=1)]

Index(['C', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

---

#### comprehension

```
[c for c in df if df[c].str.contains('%').any()]

['C', 'D']
```

---

#### `filter`

```
[*filter(lambda c: df[c].str.contains('%').any(), df)]

['C', 'D']
```

---

#### Numpy's `find`

```
from numpy.core.defchararray import find

df.columns[(find(df.to_numpy().astype(str), '%') >= 0).any(0)]

Index(['C', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

Comment: Great thinking. Thanks. I think your first method needs a bit adjustment to apply to more scenarios: for dataframes with columns of float64 data type, it wouldn't work. Seems like `str.` will just eliminate all the float64 columns.

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
df.columns[df.apply(lambda x: x.str.contains("\%")).any()]
```

Answer (score 6):

Compare with `replace` and create a mask to index the columns accordingly:

```
df.loc[:,(df != df.replace('%', '', regex=True)).any()]
     C    D
0   10  10%
1  20%  20%
2  30%   30

df.columns[(df != df.replace('%', '', regex=True)).any()]
# Index(['C', 'D'], dtype='object')
```

This avoids the need for a loop, `apply`, or `applymap`.

Answer (score 5):

Let us do `melt`

```
df.melt().loc[lambda x :x.value.str.contains('%'),'variable'].unique()
Out[556]: array(['C', 'D'], dtype=object)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Look at the below solution can work on object dtypes also.**

```
[c for c in dfif df[c].eq("CSS").any()]
```